# Unable to process request due to missing initial state

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with Angular, Ionic and Firebase and all was working well, but when I make with capacitor the app for android studio for creating the apk, when I run the app on the tablet I can't log in with Google, it says what you see in the title or error 403 when I run it on a virtual android device in android studio.

What can I do for solving this? I've been a few days reading things but nothing worked.

I tried changing the authDomain of my firebase enviroment and installing reCaptcha for verifying app(didn't manage to install it correcly).

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The best questions include code and troubleshooting. That helps us to narrow down the cause of the problem. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)